# How to compare two values with same ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am able to compare one dropdown value using ajax but not able to compare two values in the same ajax. It would be possible either by passing two values to the ajax page URL or by passing two ids to the ajax function.I want to compare date and operator id present in the op_attend table and check for attendance in the same table and display dropdown accordingly in the attendance field. All these ajax events should occur before hitting any button.Please help me out!!

```js
$('#category-list').on('change', function() {
  var state_id1 = this.value;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "checkop.php",
    data: 'state_id1=' + state_id1,
    success: function(result) {
      $("#attend1").html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<label>Date&nbsp;<span style="font-size:medium;color:red">*</span></label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker-autoclose" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="date2" class="complex-colorpicker form-control" required="" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<label>Operator Name&nbsp;<span style="font-size:medium;color:red">*</span></label>
<select class="select2 form-control custom-select" name="operator1" id="category-list" required="">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <?php
        require_once("dbcontrollernew.php");
        $db_handle1 = new DBController();
        $queryoperator ="SELECT * FROM operator where status='1'";
        $operators = $db_handle1->runQuery($queryoperator);
          foreach($operators as $op)
          {
           ?>

    <option data-price7="<?php echo htmlentities($op['id']);?>" value="<?php echo htmlentities($op['operator']);?>">
      <?php echo htmlentities($op['operator']);?>
    </option>
    <?php
        }
        ?>
</select>
<input id="opid1" style="display:none" name="opid1">

<label>Attendance&nbsp;<span style="font-size:medium;color:red">*</span></label>
<select name="attendance1" id="attend1" class="select2 form-control custom-select" required="">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>

</select>
```

```
<?php
$sfid1 = ($_REQUEST['state_id1']); 
if($sfid1!='')
{
$drawing_result1 ='select * from op_attend where opid='.$_GET['state_id1'].';
 $result1=mysqli_query($con,$drawing_result1);
while($row1 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row1['attendance'];?>"><?php echo $row1['attendance'];?></option>
<?php }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

In ajax, We have to pass the **date** and **operator id** both

```
$('#category-list').on('change', function() {
  var state_id1 = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "checkop.php",
    data: {'state_id1': state_id1, 'date' : $('#datepicker-autoclose').val()},
    success: function(result) {
      $("#attend1").html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Get date and operator id using post method:

```
<?php
$state_id1 = ($_POST['state_id1']); 
if($state_id1!='')
{
    $drawing_result ='select * from op_attend where opid='.$state_id1.' and date='.date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date']));
    $result1=mysqli_query($con,$drawing_result);
    $opt='';
    $opt.="<option value=''>Select Attendance</option>";

    while($row1 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) { 
        $opt.="<option value=".$row1['attendance_id']." >".$row1['attendance']."</option>";
    }
    echo $opt;
}
?>
```

Hope this works for you.